# graphql_flutter OnCompleted method runs multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql-flutter

Does anybody know why the OnCompleted method runs multiple times after the mutation is complete? Below is the code thats copied over from the description section of the graphql_flutter package. I have the similar setup in my code and I do see the resultData getting printed multiple times after the mutation is complete. To know my knowledge it should run once if the cache needs to be updated and not run if it is pulling the data from the cache.

I have another mutation that runs after this mutation is complete and I do see multiple records being created in the database just because of this issue.

```
Mutation(
  options: MutationOptions(
    document: gql(addStar), // this is the mutation string you just created
    update: (GraphQLDataProxy cache, QueryResult result) {
      return cache;
    },
    // or do something with the result.data on completion
    onCompleted: (dynamic resultData) {
      print(resultData);
    },
  ),
  builder: (
    RunMutation runMutation,
    QueryResult result,
  ) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => runMutation({
        'starrableId': <A_STARTABLE_REPOSITORY_ID>,
      }),
      tooltip: 'Star',
      child: Icon(Icons.star),
    );
  },
);
```